# Set up development environment proxy server

Tags: iis, iis-7, proxy, asp.net, http

I need to create a proxy server to handle external requests on a development environment and was wondering how best to go about this.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if "proxy" is the Answer to Everything here; what requirements are there that this must be accomplished through the use of a proxy, instead of, say, NAT ?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure what way the client has this set up on their environment. I could really do with replicating exactly what they have in place. I was just told they have a proxy server and to make my requests to a particular service handle it.

Comment: If they want you to replicate the prod environment exactly, then I suggest you ask them how exactly that is set up, then replicate it ;)

Comment: Just what I was thinking :)